# Transfer of apps from phone to sd card

Tags: storage

How to transfer apps & games from phone to sd card? As lumia 520 has only 7 GB memory space.I want to download other apps too but due to shortage of space,not able to do it.So is it possible that if i can transfer some of my apps and games to sd card.I tried but its not happening as there is no option regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

That's not currently possible with Windows Phone 8 (Update 3). The SD card can only store Music, Pictures, Video, and Maps.

The [Windows Phone 8.1 update is expected to add this feature](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-new-features-revealed), which is due for release around [July/August 2014](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/windows-phone-81-will-roll-out-to-users-in-july-or-august-report-484577).